# Text overflow on Stack Apps

Tags: bug, stackapps

I was just looking through [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/), and saw this beautiful bug:

[image: Bug]

Changing the font size does nothing to fix it. I have even tried hard-reloading the page. I also tried zooming out to 90 percent and it looks normal, strangely.

---

<sub>Chrome 87.0 with Windows 10</sub>

Comment: Have you tried `display: flex` to change it accordingly?

Comment: Are you zoomed to 100%?

Comment: @rene intrestingly it looks normal with 90 percent zoom, but with 100 percent it looks like the screenshot.

Comment: I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnIsX.png) in the "Apps" and "Scripts" tabs; the other tabs are OK. When the text is lengthy it intrudes on the Tag's area. --- With FF Android the zoom doesn't reflow the text, and so there's no change in what / where is overwritten.

Comment: Beautiful bug? Are you under the influence of [Antonio Radić](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonio_Radi%C4%87)?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I mainly said it as a joke :)